# UISwitch setOn(:, animated:) does not work as document

Tags: ios10, uiswitch

As Apple's document write, `UISwitch`'s function `setOn(on: Bool, animated: Bool)` does not send action. It works fine before iOS 10, but it will send action after I call it in iOS 10. I call it in "ValueChanged" event to force switch back, so I got this event action twice. is it a bug in iOS 10?

Comment: I add a delay to call `setOn(on: Bool, animated: Bool)`， action does not be called again。 So it can't call this method in action directly in iOS 10？

Comment: Did you resolved this issue on iOS 10?

Comment: @lee not yet, I add a delay, but it's not a perfect solution cause switch button flash the state.

Comment: @edison 's answer is right. let check with get main thread on iOS 10

Answer (score 11):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    sender.setOn(flag, animated: animated)
}
```

it works for me in Xcode 8.

but call `UISwitch.setOn(_:animated:)` directly on main thread doesn't work.

### Update

thanks to @codiction:

`UISwitch.setOn(_:animated:)` can be called direclty on main thread, but can't be called directly in UISwitch ValueChanged action on iOS 10.

Comment: `UISwitch.setOn(_:animated:)` can be called direclty on main thread but can't be called directly in `UISwitch` ValueChanged action

Comment: It work as strange thing on iOS 10.Because, default `setOn` call on main thread on iOS 9, but not on iOS 10.

Answer (score 8):

The following solution resolves that issue. You should dispatch_async only if trying to call [UISwitch setOn:] within the action callback of that switch itself.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [switch setOn:YES animated:YES];
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I found these solutions to partially work. However, when I used `switch.setOn(false, animated: true)` the `onTint` color would appear white in the off position. I'm assuming this is a bug but I worked around this by using this:

```
switch.setOn(false, animated: true)
switch.onTintColor = .clear
```

Don't forget to reset the `onTint` color when you're ready to allow the switch to be toggled on, if applicable.

```
switch.onTintColor = <your custom color> // Use nil to use the default onTint for UISwitch
```

Hopefully this helps save someone a little time.

Comment: Same for "thumbTintColor"