# UISwitch Bool Fails? Switch isOn not True

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiswitch

So I have a strange one.

I have a checklist app in the App Store currently. Today a user reported strange behaviour when they used a `UISwitch`.

As seen below, this is a simple switch inside a `Storyboard`, linked to an IBAction, just as I always do and have since iOS 8.

You check the switch to `on`, it changes an image to full alpha to indicate you have it, else the image remains semi-transparent and `off`.

```
- (IBAction)Switch1:(id)sender {         //IBAction linked to Switch

     if([S001 isOn]) {                   //if Switch 'S001' is ON...
         myImage.alpha = 1.0;            //make image NOT transparent     

         ...
         //save ON                       //save data using NSUserDefaults
     }
     else {                              //else switch is OFF...
         myImage.alpha = 0.3;            //make image TRANSPARENT 

         ...
         //save OFF                      //save data using NSUserDefaults
     }
}
```

Basically, when the User presses the switch, it animates and changes to `ON` but it's looking that the `if([S001 isOn])` is never called because nothing inside the `if` is called. i.e. the image doesn't change to full alpha and nothing is saved as ON.

The user is on an iPhone 6 running `iOS 10.1.1`. Now the strange thing is that I'm running iOS 10.1.1 on iPhone 7+ and it works fine. It also works throughout iOS 9 across all screen sizes.

I've done a bit of reading and found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40213611/uiswitch-action-not-work-in-ios-10) and [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39566361/uiswitch-seton-animated-does-not-work-as-document) here on Stackoverflow and it's looking like other people are experiencing similar problems.

So I'm guessing that if people have my app in iOS 9, and then upgrade to iOS 10, THAT's when they experience this problem, but I can't be sure. As it seems to be a unique case.

What could be causing this? Is there anything I can do to improve my IBAction for iOS 10 users?

Comment: Why is your `Switch1:` method acting on `S001` instead of `sender`?

Comment: @rmaddy What do you mean? `Switch1` is the `IBAction` for `S001`. Declared like this: `IBOutlet UISwitch *S001` and `-(IBAction)Switch1:(id)sender;`

Comment: @rmaddy Do I use IBAction wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The `sender` parameter will be the `UISwitch`. It's best to act on the sender and not some outside reference to the switch.

Comment: @rmaddy Oh I see. Would you mind showing me the more efficient syntax? I'm not familiar with doing it that way. All tutorials I've seen implement it this way. Thank you.

Comment: @rmaddy I think I've discovered what's happening... a drag of the switch doesn't call the if statement but a tap to switch the switch does... why is that? :(

Comment: what kind of action did you connect the UISwitch to IBACtion ? IS it value change event or toouch up inside event ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri `Touch Up Inside`. I've never used anything different... is that why I can drag out of the switch and nothing happen?

Comment: yes. You need to use event vallue changed for switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)Switch1:(UISwitch *)sender {         //IBAction linked to Switch

     if([sender isOn]) {                   //if Switch 'S001' is ON...
         myImage.alpha = 1.0;            //make image NOT transparent     

         ...
         //save ON                       //save data using NSUserDefaults
     }
     else {                              //else switch is OFF...
         myImage.alpha = 0.3;            //make image TRANSPARENT 

         ...
         //save OFF                      //save data using NSUserDefaults
     }
}
```

Try this out. This is what @rmaddy means by referencing the sender.

To ensure that this is called when you switch the switch, be sure to specify "Value Changed" event when creating the action (by rightClick-dragging the switch to the .m file)

[Dragging Switch from storyboard to .m](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhGOB.png)

[Possible Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmRCy.png)

Comment: Ohhhh I see. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I think I use `touch up inside` even for my switches. I didn't know "value changed" should be used. Is this why I can drag the switch and have nothing happen, or tap it and have something happen?

Comment: Yes exactly. Touch up inside triggers when you tap inside the view of the switch, where as value change corresponds to the value (on/off) of the switch

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it's a more efficient way to create an `IBAction` for a `UISwitch`. The solution to my problem was that I needed to set the `Sent Event` action to `Value Changed` instead of `Touch Up Inside`. This solved my problem :D